# How to store the content of an email (the email & attachments) in one file in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, email, document

SharePoint is breaking the emails apart separating the attachments from the emails were sent into, resulting in multiple files where should be only one.
Does anyone knows a solution around this issue? How to store an email and its content in one file in SharePoint?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [EmailReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.emailreceived.aspx) event handler. This is fired when an email is received, leaving you to do the processing.

It passes through an [SPEmailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spemailmessage.aspx) which contains the raw message and any attachments. Your event handler would need to extract the mail message and store it as a list item, then copy the attachments over to the [Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx) collection of the list item.